# How to store configuration data in installation package?

Tags: parameters, registry, windows-installer, installshield, filepath

My software product has an installation package created with Installshield.

The software product must point to a file path to access files specific to the site at which it is installed. This file path is stored in the registry.

Up until now I have had to modify the installation package for each client so that the registry setting points to the file path specific for that client.

I would like my installation package to be such that when a client receives it they can configure the package themselves so that it writes the client-specific setting to the registry when installed.

What is the best way to achieve this?  Is there an easy way to have an Installshield or MSI parameter to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a secure custom property  ( a property that is in CAPS and listed in the SecureCustomProperties property ) and then use that in the registry table to set the value.

Example

msiexec /I foo.msi SECUREPROPERTY=somevalue

then in the registry table reference the value like:

[SECUREPROPERTY]

You'll also want to do some custom UI work to allow the user to enter the value while running interactively.  You might also want some input validation.  Finally, you'll need to understand that properties aren't persisted for subsequent installations so you'll need to use System Search (AppSearch/RegLocator)  to pull the property back in so that it doesn't get wiped out during repairs and upgrades.

It's not that hard once you've done it a few times but it is a lot to describe.

Comment: How do `SecureCustomProperties` differ from `PublicProperties`?

Comment: In a nutshell, when you are following managed installs (/jm or UAC enabled with client side not elevated)  only properties marked as secure that get set in the UI will have their values updated in the Execute sequence.  Generally InstallShield will automatically author public properties as secure for you but it's something you should be aware of.

Comment: My main aim is to know that the setup build that I give my client is identical to my test build. Rather than deal with the issues you mention above, is there some way to alter my test build only in regard to the client specific configuration setting?  It could be just a single file in the target folder that needs to be different.

Comment: @CJ7 In the question you write that you want your clients to be able to configure the package they receive from you. Christopher gave you a solution. If you just want to automate the process of package modification, you can use WiX variables to change the package on-the-fly so that after running WiX tools you get the final "corrected" package for a specific client.

Comment: If you don't want the installer to handle configuration data, then handle it in the application on first run.  If you want to automate that for test purposes but not for production purposes, then create a script that installs the MSI and then updates the system (registry, xml file, ini file... whatever... )  to apply that data.